# I have looked through multiple times but keep getting the same error with detectMultiScale in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jadalada/Documents/GitHub/allTests/OpenCV (Py)/VCV.py", line 14, in <module>
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1658: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function
```

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

faceCascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('Casscades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eyeCascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('Casscades/haarcascade_eye.xml')
smileCascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('Casscades/haarcascade_smile.xml')

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    eyes = eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    smile = smileCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
```

I am not sure why this is happening as in another, EXACT same python file for the same EXACT code it works perfectly.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

faceCascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('Casscades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eyeCascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('Casscades/haarcascade_eye.xml')
smileCascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('Casscades/haarcascade_smile.xml')

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    eyes = eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    smile = smileCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
```

this is the exact same code in another file which runs perfectly with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Error most likely means your CascadeClassifier is not instantiated correctly. Use:

```
faceCascade.empty()
```

to check whether classifier is instantiated correctly. If this returns true, either
1- Your path to xml file is incorrect.
2- Your xml file is incorrect
3- For some reason xml file could not be loaded?

If you are sure file and path is correct, try loading it again with:

```
faceCascade.load('PATH_TO_XML')
```

Comment: omfg thx, i had a typo with my path to my xml file. <3

i feel so bad, sorry for wasting your time >:(